# How to format date string in asp.net gridview column to another style that i prefer?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, format

I would like to format some of the columns in the gridview that has string for example "200522130830" to "2020/05/22 13:08:30". How should I do this? Found may be able to use DataFormatString to do this but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

You use it the same way `String.Format` works (if its DateTime) - here is an example

```
<asp:BoundField DataFormatString="{0:MMM/dd,  HH:mm}" />
```

If its string, then you must first convert it to int, then to DateTime, then the DataFormatString will work. But if you get your data from the database, then its probably all ready DateTime format - not a string -just try it and see if its works

Comment: are there any ways to convert the string to int directly in the gridview? or I have to change in the datatable that I set as datasource? the datatable was given from another function.

Comment: @OngXiang If you make to change the string to int, then to datetime, your program will have a huge delay - its bad design to have the datetime and save it in string - for sure is not string, its an integer - there are ways to make this convert - just read the data and convert it